# Is it possible to force c++ class instantiation on the heap?

Tags: c++, class, heap-memory, instantiation

I need to use this `class` in a threaded application so instantiating it on the stack will obviously be a problem, is there a way to force `new` to be used when instantiating the class?

I have made the constructors `private` and the `new` operator public, something like

```
public:
    void *operator new(size_t);

private:
    SomeClass(void);
    SomeClass(SomeType value); 
               .
               .
               .
```

but as I expected when using

```
SomeClass *heapInstance = new SomeClass(value);
```

the compiler tells me that the constructor is private.

**Question**:

- Is there a solution to this?

**Note**: I have used this `class` all over the place, and now I need to fix my code, i.e. I need the compiler to prevent compilation so I don't need to manually search for each occurrence, I am not very good at c++ I just had to use it because I needed to do a GUI cross platform application and picked `Qt` for several reasons which are irrelevant here.

Comment: "I need to use this class in a threaded application so instantiating it on the stack will obviously be a problem" - not obvious to me, please explain! And even if you do have a good reason for saying this, just because you're only going to use it in such a way, does it really mean you should restrict it from ever being used another way? Sounds like the same argument that people use for using Singletons.

Comment: When the class instance is referenced in the new thread it might have been destroyed from the current thread, in fact that is exactly the current bug I am trying to fix.

Comment: Use a static factory function that returns a `new MyClass()` and hide the constructor.

Comment: No there isn't. There is actually an entire section on this in one of the Scott Meyers' books. (That book also covers the reverse, preventing heap allocation of for a class).

Comment: @Borgleader Oh sure, preventing heap allocation is easy, just make the `new` operator private. Is theh book downloadable anywhere?

Comment: Every thread runs on its own stack.

Comment: It sounds like you need to sort out your memory management problems. Replacing crashes with memory leaks isn't really a solution.

Comment: Provide proper copy-constructor and copy-assignment (and possibly their move equivalents) operators, and pass the object by value?If there are large amounts of data in the object, consider putting them in a structure and allocate of the heap using e.g. a shared pointer.

Comment: There will be no memory leaks, the memory will be handled by `QObject` class, there will be a `parent` to the class instance, that will be alive long enough for the thread to finish working and then delete the instance.

Comment: @iharob [They are available in ebook format yes](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html)

Comment: "I need to use this class in a threaded application... I am not very good at c++" I found your problem! :) Or the serious version: threads are explosively complicated, so I'd advise solving the problem without threads if possible, or isolating the threads from each other as much as possible so that they don't share data but instead "transfer ownership" via queue-like data structures.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker The problem is that I wasn't using threads, now I need to, so the code should be refactored.

Comment: @iharob - it would more accurate to say that you need to redesign the code. Letting a bunch of threads loose in your existing code is going to be a recipe for pain, and the problem you're trying to solve in this question is unlikely to be the last one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make ctor private/protected and provide a static method(s) to create an instance:

```
class HeapOnly {
     HeapOnly();
     HeapOnly( int i );
public:
     static HeapOnly *create() { return new HeapOnly; }
     static HeapOnly *create( int i ) { return new HeapOnly( i ); }
};
```

You may consider to return a `std::unique_ptr` in general case, but for Qt that could be not necessary.

This will not solve your problem instantly, but you will get compile error everywhere where instance is created and you can replace them by create function call catching places where class instance created on a stack.

Comment: If you return a `std::unique_ptr` that can always be coerced into a `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: This is a good solution, I can deal with it to fix the issue.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe the interface should be reordered: public, private (last thus getting explicit).